# Restore missing and/or obsolete Close-Vote Reasons

Tags: script, questions, closing

#### About:

This userscript restores missing/obsolete close-vote reasons to the close-vote dialog.

This script is in response to:

1. A [chat request](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50188645#50188645) where the poster [used it in conjunction with a bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327903/possible-to-vote-to-close-for-old-decommissioned-close-reasons-with-proof-of-c).
2. Requests, like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377878/how-do-i-close-a-question-on-teams-for-a-reason-other-than-duplicate), to restore/add the customary close reasons to *Teams* sites -- which currently only officially support closing as a duplicate?

#### Features:

- Integrates with the standard close-vote dialog.  But some of it is WIP, See the "Known issues", below.
- Adds back close reasons taken from a few SEDE queries like [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1042309/closereasontypes).
- Only Adds a reason if it is not already present.
- Works on regular sites and teams sites (but I only have 1 team to test against).
- The unofficial reasons are clearly indicated with warning iconography.

#### Screenshot:

> [image: Screenshot of enhanced close dialog]

#### Platform:

This is a userscript that runs in your browser.  It requires a userscript extension like *Tampermonkey* or *Violentmonkey*.

#### Install button: <kbd>[Install from GitHub](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange%2C%20Close%20Vote%20Reasons%2C%20Add%20em%20back.user.js)</kbd>

#### Code:

The code is [on GitHub, in the BrockA/SE-misc repository](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/blob/master/Stack%20Exchange%2C%20Close%20Vote%20Reasons%2C%20Add%20em%20back.user.js).

Post bug reports and pull requests there. <sup><sub>(Or below if you don't do GitHub.)</sub></sup>

**Known issues:**

1. Not yet sanctioned by the SE team.  **USE SPARINGLY, lest ye be banned.**
2. The "You have already voted to close this question" dialogs can't seem to get the non-standard close reason.
3. The close-vote count is not updated on a successful close-vote.  Reload the page to see that for now.
4. Although it adds back the generic *Off topic* reason, the "off-topic because..." reasons are not supported yet -- if the site does not offer them natively. (Also, it might not be sensible to on such sites due to the way the reasons and ids vary.)
5. Close-voting by low-rep users via flagging is not well tested. Seems to work, but if it glitches, I may not support it.
6. Closing from review was not tested at all.  If it glitches, I may not support it.
7. Will not support Greasemonkey 4+.  Use Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey, or equivalent.

Comment: The script no longer works as of today, as SE made changes to the close dialog. Can you please fix?